# Qt Bar Chart does not display the maximum possible value

Tags: c++, qt

I am building this example https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcharts-barchart-example.html on Windows 10.

But instead of the picture from the website I get this:
[image]

I have not changed the code in the slightest, I used Qt Creator's template projects.

Why is it not displaying the max value? Is it a windows rendering thing? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't really think that the plotted values differ, the one on the website has a different y-scale compared to the one that you show in the screenshot. (Which is why the bars appear to be "*shorter*" in your case.) It is possible that the template project in Qt uses a different scale by default.

Comment: No the code is identical. I tried to reduce the scale but the result was the same, the top value is not shown.

Comment: Can you clarify what you consider to be "the max value" / "the top value"?  Are you referring to the "Axel" bar in the "Apr" group?

Comment: Yes it should display a 13 on the Y axis like on the website, but it does not.

Comment: @user686368 what is your Qt Version?

Comment: Should have mentioned that: 6.1.2, same issue on both MSVC and MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the same code on my windows 10 machine.

Take a look at line 85 in the source code for the Qt example, main.cpp. The call to `axisY->setRange(0,15);` the range of the `axisY` object is set to a value other than the number 13. If you look carefully at the image in the webpage:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcharts-barchart-example.html

It is evident the maximum `axisY` scaling value is supposed to be 13.

You can clearly see the corrected line of code, at line 85, next to the desired output present on the website in the image here:
[image: Desired output right, corrected line of code at left.]

Sorry about the image being a little small.

Note, the line to correct is shown on the image. It is marked in the line numbers by a red line at the left in the gutter where the other line numbers are located.

Please compare against your own installation files.

Comment: Could you add a breakpoint to the lines after the call to window.show(), and a line before it? I wonder when/if the axis label ever gets dropped?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the debug information downloaded so I can't explore the Qt objects, and it will take quite a while to download 10GB.

Comment: @mikelevels what is your Qt Version?

Comment: I'm running Qt 6.1.0. I also have versions 6.0.3, and 5.15.2 locally as well, if needed. I am using MSVC2019 64-bit, I also have a toolchain for MSVC15 64-bit ready to go as needed. Additionally, I can readily download what ever setup you have if you let me know how your installation is setup. Please advise.

Comment: I installed Qt 5.15.2 and the example was exactly as it should be. No idea why this is an issue in Qt 6.1.2, oh well, thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem! Too bad we could not isolate the issue further. I strongly recommend posting to https://forum.qt.io/ when you get a chance. I was unable to locate an entry similar to your issue in the forum. You never know if this sort of thing could help the Qt open source dev team isolate and resolve analogous issues!

Comment: @user686368 It seems to me that it is a bug, I recommend you report it: https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/QTBUG/issues